# How to convert the image format to ARG1555 in QT?

Tags: qt

I'm new at qt, would like to write a new program with it that will be first. I want to change the image format and size after a image was loaded. However I can not find the ARGB1555 format in the supported formats. How can I convert its format to ARGB1555 ? I want this format, because will use it on hmi project that based on bare metal mcu, so will need the less memory.

Comment: Changing the size - yes, it's possible by scaling the image. The change of format - I really doubt that there is any such feature. You'll probably have to do this on your own (I strongly recommend not to do that) or use a third party library (plenty out there).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the raw pixeldata of a QImage

```
const uchar * QImage::bits() const
```

Cast this to int ( 4bytes = pixel ) and use this function for conversion.

```
unsigned short ARGB8888toARGB1555(unsigned int c)
{
    return (unsigned short)(((c>>16)&0x8000 | (c>>9)&0x7C00 | (c>>6)&0x03E0 | (c>>3)&0x1F));
}
```

Reference: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/118698-color-conversion.html

Comment: However there is not ARGB8888 in supported formats too,

Comment: QImage::Format_ARGB32The image is stored using a 32-bit ARGB format (0xAARRGGBB). 8+8+8+8 = 32 !